# What does [0] do in jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery

```
var example = $("#myElement")[0];
```

versus

```
var example = $("#myElement");
```

What's the difference? What's going on here? What does the example variable contain after each selection?

Comment: It returns the first element in the array-like object. The result will be the same as doing `document.getElementById('myElement')`

Comment: That would be a great answer if we took it for granted that it returns "an array-like object," which we're not doing, because I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I didn't say it returns an array like object. I said it returns the first **element** in the array like object.

Comment: The first one would only return the first `#myElement`. The second would return all `#myElement`.

Comment: is this really something you couldn't google dude?

Comment: You'd be surprised how hard it is to search for things like [0]. If you already know what it's called, it's easy to find.

Comment: Have you tryed console.log() your examples? The first one returns the actual element, the second one returns an array that happens to have just one element.

Comment: @cernunnos, the second returns a jQuery object which is similar to arrays ("array-like") and therefore consoles will tend to show it as though it were an actual instance of Array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery objects (the value returned from the `$` function) are a collection ("array-like" object) of DOM elements.  `$("#myElement")[0]` gets the 1st element from that array, a native DOM element.

You can also do `$("#myElement").get(0)`.

Comment: array-like object, technically.

Comment: But then why can you do things like $("#myElement").hide(). Why don't you have to do $("#myElement")[0].hide()?

Comment: I personally wouldn't use `$("#myElement")` as an example here since `$("#myElement")` should always return one element as IDs are supposed to be unique. A class (`$(".myElement")`) might be a more realistic example.

Comment: No, that's my point exactly. Why would you ever use [0] with IDs since there's only one? Is that to say using [0] makes no difference if the array-like object is of size 1?

Comment: @Aerovistae: Because `.hide()` is a jQuery method.  Native DOM elements don't have a `.hide()` method.

Comment: @Aerovistae: All `[0]` does is "convert" a jQuery object into a "native" [DOM element object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element).

Comment: @j08691: Yes, but you still may do `$("#myElement")[0]` instead of doing `document.getElementById('myElement')` if if you want the DOM element object.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#myElement")[0]` selects the first item returned by your selector

`$("#myElement")` gives you every item returned by the selector.

You are using an id in your example, so you should only ever have 1 item with any given id

However if you did this for example

`$('.test').hide()`, it would hide every element with a class of test.

Whereas `$('.test')[0].hide()` would only hide the first item

Comment: `$('.test')[0].hide()` wouldn't work as `.hide()` is a jQuery method and `[0]` gives you a native DOM element object.

Comment: `$('.test').get(0)` is equivalent to `$('.test')[0]`.  You want `$('.test').eq(0)`.